# check if a widget is on screen

Tags: flutter, widget

Is there a way to detect if a widget is on screen/seen anywhere on the app. For example in a `TabBar` or a `PageView`.

I already know that I could use the widget's build method to detect this, but this results in some really weird behavior where sometimes the widget has already been built and when the user navigates to the screen nothing happens.

So is there any way to do this with an entire app?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try using widget key like a Global Key

`final key = GlobalKey();`

and they passes it to the widget you want to know the state